# How to Submit PDF through email

Tags: javascript, pdf, submit, dotnetnuke

We have a complex form that we created as a PDF. We want users to be able fill out the PDF and then either print it out and mail it in or click a Submit button and have it emailed to the client. What's the best way to do this?

I understand that we can attach javascript to the Submit button on the form. I'm thinking we could use Javascript to submit the form to the website and then write a REST type page that would handle emailing the PDF to the appropriate place. We are using ASP.NET/DotNetNuke on the backend of the site.

Comment: I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that

Answer (score 1):

Dave,

You have a few options on this but a lot of it is going to be depending on how you want the user to handle input.

If you want the user to fill the ACTUAL PDF themselves, then you have a lot less control.  But it can submit to a location and go from there, but saving it as a modified filled PDF requires either licensing for the document, OR for the users to have the full version of acrobat.

Another option is for you to build an input form for the user, then fill the PDF and commit the information, then either send them the file if they want to print or e-mail it off yourself.

I've done both in the past for previous clients/jobs.  Feel free to ping me directly with a bit more detail if this doesn't help.

**Edit - More detail based on comment**

In this situation you have a few options.

1. Actually it looks like you can get to part of this now via the PDF create process - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Acrobat/9.0/Standard/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7e0d.w.html
2. From a server side sending you have a few options.  They can save it and upload it, which isn't best.
3. You can have a form post action, this will submit their answers to your server, you could then plug them into a PDF, save it, then forward it on

In the end it will depend on the true workflow.

Comment: Hi Mitchell, I do want users to fill out the PDF. It's a pretty complex form and we already have that part implemented, it's just the submit part I need to get done. We certainly can't require that users have the full version of Acrobat as this is a PDF for public Job Applicants to fill out. So, your saying we need the "licensing for the document" option? Where can I find out about that?

Comment: Ok, so for this you have a few options, see my updated post in about 2 minutes....

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered this SaaS? http://www.pdfescape.com/what/publishing/

Comment: I took a look. Not a big fan of an annual fee per PDF.